# Print something completely different when the LP is infeasible in MathProg

Tags: ampl, glpk, feasibility, mathprog

I’m using MathProg (a language specific to the GLPK library, resembling a subset of AMPL) to find topological ranking of vertices of a graph. It’s an assignment for my linear programming class. It’s an introductory exercise to make sure we can formulate a simple linear program and solve it using GLPK.

I’ve written a Perl script that generates the linear program in MathProg for a given graph. It prints values of the variables (ranks of vertices) via `printf`. If it’s feasible, that’s exactly what I want; otherwise **it prints all zeros, but I want to print just `Infeasible, has cycles or loops.`.**

I managed to do it in a hacky way (see below). **How to do it more elegantly, without repeating the condition for feasibility? Is there a way to detect infeasibility that does not depend on the problem being solved?**

```
param Vsize := 3;
set V "Vertices" := (0..Vsize-1);
set E "Edges" within V cross V := {(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)};

var v{i in V} >= 0;
minimize rank_total: sum{i in V} v[i];
edge{(i, j) in E}: v[j] - v[i] >= 1;

solve;

printf "#OUTPUT:\n";
printf (if ((exists{i in V} v[i] >= 1) or card(E) = 0) then "" else "Infeasible, has cycles or loops.\n");
printf{i in V} (if ((exists{j in V} v[j] >= 1) or card(E) = 0) then "v_%d: %d\n" else ""), i, v[i];
printf "#OUTPUT END\n";

end;
```

I tried to declare `param Feasible binary := (exists{i in V} v[i] >= 1) or card(E) = 0;` but GLPK refused it with `Model processing error`. When I declared it before `solve`, it said `operand preceding >= has invalid type`, when after, it said `expression following := has invalid type`. I was seeking something like a variable in common programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AMPL you can check the built-in parameter `solve_result` to see if the problem is infeasible:

```
if solve_result = 'infeasible' then
  print 'Infeasible, has cycles or loops.';
```

However, I'm not sure if GLPK supports this parameter in which case you might need to check for feasibility manually.

As for the error, since `exists` is a logical expression you can't use it as a numeric one. The fix is to simply put logical expression in `if`:

```
param Feasible binary :=
  if (exists{i in V} v[i].val >= 1) or card(E) = 0 then 1;
```

Comment: My `glpsol` accepts the definition of `Feasible` param only after `solve` and with `v[i].val` replaced with just `v[i]`.

Comment: MathProg has no `print` function and no `if` statement. It has only the `if` operator. Also `solve_result` is probably not supported, because `printf (if solve_result = 'infeasible' then "Infeasible, has cycles or loops.\n" else "");` gives me `solve_result not defined`. But thanks anyway, I did not realize that logical values are not considered numeric (unlike e.g. in C).

Comment: I'm glad that I managed to help despite my limited knowledge of glpk =).